# Laravel error Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ HttpException

Tags: laravel, error-handling, routes

My application was working fine in Ubuntu but after migrating it into windows machine (local) the following error is being displayed

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ HttpException
```

Here is my code of routes.php

```
/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Application Routes
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
  | It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
  | and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
  |
 */
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::any('/signup', 'HomeController@signup');
Route::any('/login', 'HomeController@login');
Route::get('/logout', 'HomeController@logout');

// Custom routes for admin section
Route::any('admin/login', 'AdminController@login');
Route::get('admin/logout', 'AdminController@logout');
Route::any('admin/permissions/get-role-permissions', 'PermissionsController@get_role_permissions');
Route::any('admin/permissions/configure', 'PermissionsController@configure');

// Grouped routes for admin section
Route::group(array('before' => 'adminauth', 'except' => array('/admin/login', '/admin/logout')), function() {
    Route::resource('/admin/roles', 'RolesController');
    Route::resource('/admin/permissions', 'PermissionsController');
    Route::resource('/admin', 'AdminController');

});

// Grouped routes for front end
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
    Route::resource('/dashboard', 'UserController@index');
    Route::resource('/posts', 'PostsController');
});
```

When i invoke /admin/roles or /admin/permissions/configure then i get the above error, however it works fine for /admin only.

Comment: `Route::resource('/admin/roles', array('uses' => 'RolesController'));` Try like this.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your routes and the last route group:

```
// Grouped routes for front end
Route::group(array('before'=>'auth'), function() {
    // You cannot use Route::resource and use a controller method,
    // you need to use an entire controller.
    //
    // Route::resource('/dashboard','UserController@index'); // !!
    Route::get('/dashboard','UserController@index'); // here was the error
    // ...
});
```